# Burp proxy interception doesn't work for localhosted web apps with Firefox

Tags: firefox, proxy, burp, interception

Although I can and do use the `Burp` proxy with `Firefox` for remote web servers without any problem, I can't seem to get it to work on the local network with test web applications I host on my local server.

`Burp` cannot see traffic from these requests. What am I missing? Some solutions suggested in related questions here did not help me at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To proxy `localhost` (and related addresses) with newer `Firefox` versions (>=67), the preference `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` (accessible through the `about:config` page) must be set to `true`.

**Details on why `Mozilla` decided to use specific rules for localhost;**

In 2018, Jann Horn [reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1503393) a major security vulnerability. According to his report, applications that bind a web server to `localhost` and then use [Host Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) checks, to prevent [DNS rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) attacks, should be protected from malicious outside traffic, even if the network itself is malicious. Back then, `localhost` was not treated differently in proxying decisions by `Firefox`. That meant that an attacker could abuse [Web Proxy Auto-Discovery (WPAD) Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol) to gain the ability to serve attacker-controlled content at `http://localhost>:*/*`. So the attacker could be able to perform same-origin [XMLHttpRequest (XHR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to `http://localhost>:*/*` (e.g. by letting the [proxy auto-config (PAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file specify `DIRECT` as fallback, if the proxy went down).

In 2019, Mozilla's developers decided to create and "hide" the above mentioned preference in the config page, in order to protect inexperienced users. The [fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1507110) was finally released with [version 67](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?f1=cf_status_firefox67&o1=equals&query_format=advanced&v1=fixed&order=bug_status%2Cpriority%2Cassigned_to%2Cbug_id&limit=0).